# WM_KEYDOWN and WM_COMMAND

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-interface

when i pressed a button in window, i couldn't use key like VK_RETURN to perform an action
,i notice that a button always down after i pressed it
,someone knows how to fix it?

```
case WM_CREATE:{
CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"),TEXT("button"),WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,10,10,100,50,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_BT,NULL,NULL);
break;
}
case WM_KEYDOWN:{
        switch(wParam){
        case VK_RETURN:
        MessageBox(hwnd,"enter","keydown",MB_OK);
        break;
        }
        break;
    }
case WM_COMMAND:{
        switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
        case ID_BT: CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"),TEXT(""),WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER
            |ES_AUTOHSCROLL,10,cc,100,20,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_TBms,NULL,NULL);
        break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: OMG Don't write low level Windows GUI code. You're in for a world of pain. Use Afx or MFC (ouch) or something. Haven't seen this stuff for at least 17 years.

Comment: u're right but i must write it in low level because my teacher ask me to do it t.t

Comment: You need to show more than this. Show your message loop.. Show your window procedure..

Comment: There are no buttons in your code. So where does this problem happen? Where does it say the button is always down? Please edit your question with more info.

Comment: Bet your message loop is looking at all messages, instead of just the messages for your window, so you are picking up messages for the newly created window msg box

Comment: thanks for your help, i found a solution

Comment: @chris no. The dialog runs its own modal message pump.

Comment: Assuming that your controls are on a dialog what you describe is the expected behavior: The dialog manager translates `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` messages for the enter key to a corresponding `WM_COMMAND` for the button that currently has the focus, or the default button if no button currently has the input focus. @EJP *"Use Afx"* does not compile to make any sense, whatsoever. Stop being clueless.